# Bad Token on line 1 with print statement

Tags: python, syntax, token

I couldn't find anything online that would help so I'm asking here.  I want to format my print statement like this:

```
print("
1.)It really do be like that sometimes
2.)ok
3.)uhhhhhhhh
")
```

When I try to run it however, it says "SyntaxError: bad token on line 1 in main.py" and I don't know what I did wrong.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have linebreaks in a string literal like that. Try replacing your code with this:

```
print("\n1.)It really do be like that sometimes\n2.)ok\n3.)uhhhhhhhh\n")
```

Comment: Thanks chief.  I have to wait 9 minutes to set as answer but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use triple-quote string syntax:

`print("""
1.)It really do be like that sometimes
2.)ok
3.)uhhhhhhhh
""")`

For extra clarity couple it with `textwrap.dedent()`:

`import textwrap
print(textwrap.dedent("""
    1.)It really do be like that sometimes
    2.)ok
    3.)uhhhhhhhh
    """))`